# PendingResult<> not calling onResult Callback.

Tags: android, autocomplete, google-places-api

In the past few months I have had create an autocomplete search bar in my android app. This would list 3 places as in actual geo locations from the Places api that google has, and several more places that I loaded from my own database of stores.

Now the problem is, that this used to work but now it doesn't.
I have tried using the latest libraries and such but it isn't helping. I double checked my api key and since i'm using the maps functionality as well I know that it works since it shows me the map.

The relavant code is this.

```
PendingResult<AutocompletePredictionBuffer> placesBuffer = Places.GeoDataApi
            .getAutocompletePredictions(googleApiClient, searchString, null, geoFilter);

 placesBuffer.setResultCallback(adapter);
```

I am setting the result callback to an adapter that implements the callback interface and has a method callback `onResult(AutocompletePredictionBuffer autocompletePredictionBuffer)` and in this I handle the data and set it up to show in the autocompletion list.

I put a simple Log.i in the onresult and it doesn't seem to be called anymore.

Would anyone know how to solve this problem, or can tell me how I can retrieve any of the possible "error codes"?

Note: This all used to work before up until a few weeks ago.

The used api functions are decribed here, just in case:
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/GeoDataApi